# ul list disappears when not using overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

In this example, the list disappears when not using the overflow property with the hidden value.Can some one explain why ?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's a link to the tutorial: [:https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp)

Comment: Because that’s how `float` works. https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: I would say don't use float anymore - look for a tutorial about flex or grid